# Получить данные из input по нажатию кнопки

Tags: angular2

Есть текст и кнопка на экране.

```
<span>Text</span>
<button>Edit text</button>
```

Необходимо, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, вместо текста, появлялся `input`, а текст кнопки менялся на **Sumbit**. Для этого, в модели задаю св-во, скажем, `isEditing` и метод, меняющий это св-во, скажем `changeTextStatus`. В представлении связываю своё св-во и метод с элеметами:

```
<span *ngIf="!isEditing">Text</span>
<input #inputValue *ngIf="isEditing" type="text" />
<button (click)="changeTextStatus(inputValue)">{{ isEditing ? 'Submit' : 'Edit' }}</button>
```

Пусть в методе changeTextStatus (для краткости примера) берется значение из input и что-о с ним делается. Проблема в том, что всегда приходит `undefined`, я подозреваю потому, что на инпуте висит директива ngIf, т.к. без неё всё отлично передаётся. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема из-за того, что вы сразу не инициализировали свойство, на которое ссылаетесь. Сделайте в вашей модели так: **isEditing = false**.

Также обратите внимание на шаблонную переменную **#input**. Она ссылается на DOM-элемент данного *input*, который является объектом, а *value* - его свойством. Поэтому правильным синтаксисом будет *input.value*.

```
<span *ngIf="!isEditing">Text</span>
<input #input *ngIf="isEditing" type="text" />
<button (click)="changeTextStatus(input.value)">{{ isEditing ? 'Submit' : 'Edit' }}</button>
```